# How to convert hardcoded derived columns to dynamic automated columns with plsql and c#

Tags: c#

So I have fulfilled the basic requirements of this task which is to get the sum of the incomes and expenses of each customer for each month but the thing is after every month, I'll have to update the c# code and the script manually as it does not update automatically which is not very efficient. The table in the db is designed to have data from january of current year to previous month of same year and then the said previous month will have budget value, variance and then achieved and then the rest of the columns, ytdactualvalue etc. We are in july so we have data from jan to jun. Next month (august), data for july will come in and I'll have to change the code manually to accommodate the july column and change june budget, variance and achieved to that of july and also add july to pbt sum.

Below is the current code in the repository class. I have tried a for loop initially with DateTime.Now.Month -1 but it didn't work.

```
    public async Task<(List<CprSummary> mainReport, List<ExcludedIncomeType> excludedTab)> GetDoubleCPRSummaryByCustNo(string custno)
        {
            List<CprSummary> mainReport = new List<CprSummary>();
            List<ExcludedIncomeType> excludedTab = new List<ExcludedIncomeType>();

            string query = @"WITH unpivoted_data AS (
  select period,
       to_char(to_date(period || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY') yrs,
       to_char(to_date(period || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'Mon') mnths,
       cust_no,
       customer_name,
       cpr_metrics,
       income_type,
       cprmetrics_values
  from (select cust_no, customer_name, account_count, period,case
                 when cpr_metrics in
                      ('ftp_income', 'ftp_expense', 'ftp_expense_subsidy', 'ftp_income_subsidy') then 
                  'Net Ftp Income'
                  when cpr_metrics in ('interest_expense') then 'Interest Expense'
                 when cpr_metrics in (
                                      'interest_income',
                                      'interest_suspense') then
                  'Interest Income'
               
                 when cpr_metrics in ('atm_commissions',
                                      'cards_fee',
                                      'internet_banking',
                                      'mobile_banking',
                                      'pos_commissions',
                                      'sms_fee',
                                      'fx_gain_or_loss_cards') then
                   'Ebusiness Fee'
                  --other income and expense types
                  when cpr_metrics in('allocated_cost') then 'Allocated Expense'
               else
                  initcap(replace(cpr_metrics, '_', ' '))
               end income_type, cpr_metrics, SUM(cprmetrics_values) AS cprmetrics_values
               from finance.retracted unpivot(cprmetrics_values for cpr_metrics in(dep_act_bal as
                                                                                         'Deposit Actual Balance',
                                                                                         dep_avg_bal as
                                                                                         'Deposit Average Balance',
                                                                                         channels_cards_income as 
                                                                                         'Ebusiness Fee',
                                                                                         loans_act_bal as
                                                                                         'loans_actual_balance',
                                                                                         loans_avg_bal as
                                                                                         'loans_average_balance',
                                                                                         trade_act_bal as
                                                                                         'trade_actual_balance',
                                                                                         trade_avg_bal as
                                                                                         'trade_average_balance',
                                                                                         ftp_income as
                                                                                         'ftp_income',
                                                                                         ftp_income_subsidy as
                                                                                         'ftp_income_subsidy',
                                                                                         int_expense as
                                                                                         'interest_expense',
                                                                                         int_expense as 
                                                                                         'Interest Expense',
                                                                                         net_ftp_inc as
                                                                                         'Net Ftp Income',
--others
                                                                                         direct_expense as
                                                                                         'Direct Expense',
                                                                                         other_income as 
                                                                                         'Other Income'))
                 where to_char(to_date(period, 'rrrrmm'), 'rrrr') = to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'), -1),'rrrr')
               AND  cust_no = :custno 
                group by cust_no, customer_name, account_count,
                case
                 when cpr_metrics in
                      ('ftp_income', 'ftp_expense', 'ftp_expense_subsidy', 'ftp_income_subsidy') then
                  'Net Ftp Income'
                  when cpr_metrics in ('interest_expense') then 'Interest Expense'
                 when cpr_metrics in (
                                      'interest_income',
                                      'interest_suspense') then
                  'Interest Income'
               
                 when cpr_metrics in ('atm_commissions',
                                      'cards_fee',
                                      'internet_banking',
                                      'mobile_banking',
                                      'pos_commissions',
                                      'sms_fee',
                                      'fx_gain_or_loss_cards') then
                  'Ebusiness Fee'
                  --other income and expense types
                  when cpr_metrics in('allocated_cost') then 'Allocated Expense'              
               else
                  initcap(replace(cpr_metrics, '_', ' '))
               end , period, cpr_metrics                  
                )
 where cust_no = :custno
),
pivoted_data AS (
  SELECT cust_no,
         customer_name,
         cpr_metrics,
         income_type,
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202301' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""Jan_2023"",
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202302' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""Feb_2023"",
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202303' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""Mar_2023"",
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202304' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""Apr_2023"",
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202305' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""May_2023"",
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202306' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""Jun_2023"",                      
         MAX(CASE WHEN period = '202306' THEN 100 END) AS ""Jun_2023_Budget_Value"",
         (MAX(CASE WHEN period = '202306' THEN 100 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202306' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END)) AS ""Jun_2023_Variance"",
        (SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202306' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) / MAX(CASE WHEN period = '202306' THEN 100 END)) * 100 AS ""Jun_2023_Achieved"",
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202307' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""Jul_2023"",
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202308' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""Aug_2023"",
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202309' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""Sep_2023"",
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202310' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""Oct_2023"",
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202311' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""Nov_2023"",
         SUM(CASE WHEN period = '202312' THEN cprmetrics_values ELSE 0 END) AS ""Dec_2023"",
         SUM(cprmetrics_values) AS YTD_ACTUAL_VALUES,
         100 AS YTD_BUDGET_VALUES,
         100 * SUM(cprmetrics_values) / 100 AS YTD_ACHIEVED,
         100 - SUM(cprmetrics_values) AS VARIANCE,
         100 as FULL_YEAR_BUDGET,
         round((100 - SUM(cprmetrics_values)) / (select count(*) from
          (SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'month'), LEVEL - 1) AS month_name
            FROM dual
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12)
            where to_char(month_name,'rrrr') = to_char(trunc(sysdate),'rrrr')
            and month_name >= trunc(sysdate,'month')), 2) as RUN_RATE
         FROM unpivoted_data
  GROUP BY cust_no, customer_name, cpr_metrics, income_type
)
SELECT *
FROM pivoted_data
WHERE cust_no = :custno
ORDER BY income_type
";

            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionStrings.financeOra))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(":custno", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = custno;
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                var rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                var cprDict = new SortedDictionary<string, CprSummary>(new IncomeTypeComparer());

                decimal pbtJan = 0;
                decimal pbtFeb = 0;
                decimal pbtMar = 0;
                decimal pbtApr = 0;
                decimal pbtMay = 0;
                decimal pbtJun = 0;
                decimal pbtJul = 0;
                decimal pbtAug = 0;
                decimal pbtSep = 0;
                decimal pbtOct = 0;
                decimal pbtNov = 0;
                decimal pbtDec = 0;
                string customerName = null;
                string customerNo = null;

                while (await rdr.ReadAsync())
                {
                    string incomeType = rdr["income_type"].ToString();

                    if (incomeType != "Deposit Actual Balance" &&
                        incomeType != "Deposit Average Balance" &&
                        incomeType != "Loans Actual Balance" &&
                        incomeType != "Loans Average Balance" &&
                        incomeType != "Profitability" &&
                        incomeType != "Trade Actual Balance" &&
                        incomeType != "Trade Average Balance")
                    {
                        decimal valueJan = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jan_2023"].ToString());
                        decimal valueFeb = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Feb_2023"].ToString());
                        decimal valueMar = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Mar_2023"].ToString());
                        decimal valueApr = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Apr_2023"].ToString());
                        decimal valueMay = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["May_2023"].ToString());
                        decimal valueJun = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jun_2023"].ToString());
                        decimal valueJul = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jul_2023"].ToString());
                        decimal valueAug = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Aug_2023"].ToString());
                        decimal valueSep = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Sep_2023"].ToString());
                        decimal valueOct = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Oct_2023"].ToString());
                        decimal valueNov = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Nov_2023"].ToString());
                        decimal valueDec = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Dec_2023"].ToString());

                        pbtJan += valueJan;
                        pbtFeb += valueFeb;
                        pbtMar += valueMar;
                        pbtApr += valueApr;
                        pbtMay += valueMay;
                        pbtJun += valueJun;
                        pbtJul += valueJul;
                        pbtAug += valueAug;
                        pbtSep += valueSep;
                        pbtOct += valueOct;
                        pbtNov += valueNov;
                        pbtDec += valueDec;

                        customerName = rdr["customer_name"].ToString();
                        customerNo = rdr["cust_no"].ToString();

                        if (!cprDict.ContainsKey(incomeType))
                        {
                            cprDict[incomeType] = new CprSummary
                            {
                                CustomerName = rdr["customer_name"].ToString(),
                                CustomerNo = rdr["cust_no"].ToString(),
                                IncomeType = incomeType,
                                Jan_2023 = rdr["Jan_2023"].ToString(),
                                Feb_2023 = rdr["Feb_2023"].ToString(),
                                Mar_2023 = rdr["Mar_2023"].ToString(),
                                Apr_2023 = rdr["Apr_2023"].ToString(),
                                May_2023 = rdr["May_2023"].ToString(),
                                Jun_2023 = rdr["Jun_2023"].ToString(),
                                Jun_2023_Budget_Value = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jun_2023_Budget_Value"].ToString()),
                                Jun_2023_Variance = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jun_2023_Variance"].ToString()),
                                Jun_2023_Achieved = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jun_2023_Achieved"].ToString()),
                                Jul_2023 = rdr["Jul_2023"].ToString(),
                                Aug_2023 = rdr["Aug_2023"].ToString(),
                                Sep_2023 = rdr["Sep_2023"].ToString(),
                                Oct_2023 = rdr["Oct_2023"].ToString(),
                                Nov_2023 = rdr["Nov_2023"].ToString(),
                                Dec_2023 = rdr["Dec_2023"].ToString(),
                                YTD_ACTUAL_VALUE = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["YTD_ACTUAL_VALUES"].ToString()),
                                YTD_BUDGET_VALUE = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["YTD_BUDGET_VALUES"].ToString()),
                                Variance = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["VARIANCE"].ToString()),
                                YTD_ACHIEVED = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["YTD_ACHIEVED"].ToString()),
                                Full_Year_Budget = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["FULL_YEAR_BUDGET"].ToString()),
                                RunRate = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["RUN_RATE"].ToString()),
                                Dropdown = new SortedSet<DropdownItem>(new DropdownItemComparer())
                            };
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DropdownItem dropdownItem = new DropdownItem
                            {
                                CustomerName = rdr["customer_name"].ToString(),
                                CustomerNo = rdr["cust_no"].ToString(),
                                IncomeType = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(rdr["cpr_metrics"].ToString().Replace("_", " ")),
                                Jan_2023 = rdr["Jan_2023"].ToString(),
                                Feb_2023 = rdr["Feb_2023"].ToString(),
                                Mar_2023 = rdr["Mar_2023"].ToString(),
                                Apr_2023 = rdr["Apr_2023"].ToString(),
                                May_2023 = rdr["May_2023"].ToString(),
                                Jun_2023 = rdr["Jun_2023"].ToString(),
                                Jun_2023_Budget_Value = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jun_2023_Budget_Value"].ToString()),
                                Jun_2023_Variance = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jun_2023_Variance"].ToString()),
                                Jun_2023_Achieved = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jun_2023_Achieved"].ToString()),
                                Jul_2023 = rdr["Jul_2023"].ToString(),
                                Aug_2023 = rdr["Aug_2023"].ToString(),
                                Sep_2023 = rdr["Sep_2023"].ToString(),
                                Oct_2023 = rdr["Oct_2023"].ToString(),
                                Nov_2023 = rdr["Nov_2023"].ToString(),
                                Dec_2023 = rdr["Dec_2023"].ToString(),
                                YTD_ACTUAL_VALUE = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["YTD_ACTUAL_VALUES"].ToString()),
                                YTD_BUDGET_VALUE = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["YTD_BUDGET_VALUES"].ToString()),
                                Variance = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["VARIANCE"].ToString()),
                                YTD_ACHIEVED = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["YTD_ACHIEVED"].ToString()),
                                Full_Year_Budget = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["FULL_YEAR_BUDGET"].ToString()),
                                RunRate = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["RUN_RATE"].ToString())
                            };
                            cprDict[incomeType].Dropdown.Add(dropdownItem);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ExcludedIncomeType excludedIncomeType = new ExcludedIncomeType
                        {
                            IncomeType = incomeType,
                            CustomerName = rdr["customer_name"].ToString(),
                            CustomerNo = rdr["cust_no"].ToString(),
                            Jan_2023 = rdr["Jan_2023"].ToString(),
                            Feb_2023 = rdr["Feb_2023"].ToString(),
                            Mar_2023 = rdr["Mar_2023"].ToString(),
                            Apr_2023 = rdr["Apr_2023"].ToString(),
                            May_2023 = rdr["May_2023"].ToString(),
                            Jun_2023 = rdr["Jun_2023"].ToString(),
                            Jun_2023_Budget_Value = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jun_2023_Budget_Value"].ToString()),
                            Jun_2023_Variance = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jun_2023_Variance"].ToString()),
                            Jun_2023_Achieved = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["Jun_2023_Achieved"].ToString()),
                            Jul_2023 = rdr["Jul_2023"].ToString(),
                            Aug_2023 = rdr["Aug_2023"].ToString(),
                            Sep_2023 = rdr["Sep_2023"].ToString(),
                            Oct_2023 = rdr["Oct_2023"].ToString(),
                            Nov_2023 = rdr["Nov_2023"].ToString(),
                            Dec_2023 = rdr["Dec_2023"].ToString(),
                            YTD_ACTUAL_VALUE = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["YTD_ACTUAL_VALUES"].ToString()),
                            YTD_BUDGET_VALUE = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["YTD_BUDGET_VALUES"].ToString()),
                            Variance = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["VARIANCE"].ToString()),
                            YTD_ACHIEVED = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["YTD_ACHIEVED"].ToString()),
                            Full_Year_Budget = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["FULL_YEAR_BUDGET"].ToString()),
                            RunRate = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["RUN_RATE"].ToString())
                        };
                        excludedTab.Add(excludedIncomeType);
                    }
                }

                decimal pbtBudgetValue = 100;
                decimal ytdBudgetValue = 100;
                decimal pbtJunVariance = pbtBudgetValue - pbtMay;
                decimal pbtJunAchieved = (pbtJun / pbtBudgetValue) * 100;
                decimal pbtYtdActualValues = pbtJan + pbtFeb + pbtMar + pbtApr + pbtMay + pbtJun;
                decimal fullYearBudget = 100;
                int monthsLeft = (12 - DateTime.Now.Month) + 1;

                CprSummary pbtCprSummary = new CprSummary
                {
                    CustomerName = customerName,
                    CustomerNo = customerNo,
                    IncomeType = "Profit Before Tax",
                    Jan_2023 = pbtJan.ToString(),
                    Feb_2023 = pbtFeb.ToString(),
                    Mar_2023 = pbtMar.ToString(),
                    Apr_2023 = pbtApr.ToString(),
                    May_2023 = pbtMay.ToString(),
                    Jun_2023_Budget_Value = pbtBudgetValue,
                    Jun_2023_Variance = pbtJunVariance,
                    Jun_2023_Achieved = pbtJunAchieved,
                    Jun_2023 = pbtJun.ToString(),
                    Jul_2023 = pbtJul.ToString(),
                    Aug_2023 = pbtAug.ToString(),
                    Sep_2023 = pbtSep.ToString(),
                    Oct_2023 = pbtOct.ToString(),
                    Nov_2023 = pbtNov.ToString(),
                    Dec_2023 = pbtDec.ToString(),
                    YTD_ACTUAL_VALUE = pbtYtdActualValues,
                    YTD_BUDGET_VALUE = ytdBudgetValue,
                    Variance = ytdBudgetValue - pbtYtdActualValues,
                    YTD_ACHIEVED = (pbtYtdActualValues / ytdBudgetValue) * 100,
                    Full_Year_Budget = fullYearBudget,
                    RunRate = Math.Round((fullYearBudget - pbtYtdActualValues) / monthsLeft, 2)
                };
                mainReport.AddRange(cprDict.Values);
                mainReport.Remove(pbtCprSummary);
                mainReport.Add(pbtCprSummary);

                return (mainReport, excludedTab);
            }
        }`

    public class CprSummary
    {
        public string CustomerNo { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string IncomeType { get; set; }
        public string Jan_2023 { get; set; }
        public string Feb_2023 { get; set; }
        public string Mar_2023 { get; set; }
        public string Apr_2023 { get; set; }
        public string May_2023 { get; set; }
        public string Jun_2023 { get; set; }
        public decimal Jun_2023_Budget_Value { get; set; }
        public decimal Jun_2023_Variance { get; set; }
        public decimal Jun_2023_Achieved { get; set; }
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        public string Jul_2023 { get; set; }
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        public string Aug_2023 { get; set; }
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        public string Sep_2023 { get; set; }
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        public string Oct_2023 { get; set; }
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        public string Nov_2023 { get; set; }
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        public string Dec_2023 { get; set; }
        public decimal YTD_ACTUAL_VALUE { get; set; }
        public decimal YTD_BUDGET_VALUE { get; set; }
        public decimal Variance { get; set; }
        public decimal YTD_ACHIEVED { get; set; }
        public decimal Full_Year_Budget { get; set; }
        public decimal RunRate { get; set; }
        public SortedSet<DropdownItem> Dropdown { get; set; } = new SortedSet<DropdownItem>(); 
    }
```

As you can see here, when we reach August, I'll have to remove the jun columns with budget, variance and achieved manually and add july's. But I need it to automate. Any help will greatly be appreciated please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve issue with a simple array.  You will need to also modify the variable names pbtJunVariance and pbtJunAchieved.  You will also need to handle January different since month -2 will be outside the index of the array.

```
                decimal[] pbtArray = {pbtJan, pbtFeb, pbtMar, pbtApr, pbtMay, pbtJun, pbtJul, pbtAug, pbtSep, pbtOct, pbtNov, pbtDec};
                decimal pbtBudgetValue = 100;
                decimal ytdBudgetValue = 100;
                
                decimal pbtJunVariance = pbtBudgetValue - pbtArray[DateTime.Now.Month -1];
                decimal pbtJunAchieved = (pbtArray[DateTime.Now.Month - 2] / pbtBudgetValue) * 100;
                decimal pbtYtdActualValues = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < DateTime.Now.Month; i++)
                {
                   pbtYtdActualValues += pbtArray[i];
                }
                decimal fullYearBudget = 100;
                int monthsLeft = (12 - DateTime.Now.Month) + 1;
```

Comment: So this makes pbt more dynamic but the fundamental problem of having to update the code for cprsummary, dropdownitem and excluded to accommodate for new month data is still there.

Comment: The values for the months should all be arrays which would solve the issue.  You posting only asked to handle the pbt values which obviously you were editing.  The cprsummary and dropdownitem did not look like there were any edits you were making so I did not modify the code.

Comment: Please can you show me how you'll modify for dropdownitem for instance?

Comment: I do not know what you want changed.

Comment: The columns, Jan_2023, Feb_2023, etc are derived as you can see from the script, I want to make them dynamic that they update themselves each month. I'm using jsonignore to hide the null months but when they're no longer null, I shouldn't have to come to remove the jsonignore and update for the budget, variance and achieved. You showed me how to fix pbt, I'm asking how you'll apply that to the dropdown for instance.

Comment: What error do you get if you remove all the JsonIgnore?  Maybe set the values to zero.

Comment: They are already set to zero and I don't get any errors. You still don't get me. I want only months with data to show that is from January to previous month but it should always automate itself not me editing every new month manually.

Comment: Why do you need the JsonIgnore?  If you are not getting any errors these statement are not needed so simply remove them.  Then you do not need to edit the file each month.